# Public web service with jar file

Tags: java, web-services

My two class files:

**`Publish.java`**

```
class Publish() {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ............
    Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish("url", new ClassA())
    //.......
  }
}
```

**`ClassA.java`**

```
@WebService
class ClassA() {
  @WebMethod 
  public getDetails() {
    //............
    //SQL Connections
    //.......
  }
}
```

In `ClassA`, I have a SQL connection so I've added a jar file. I compiled with:

```
javac -cp .:sqljdbc4-2.0.jar ClassA.java
```

Now I published it, When I invoke the service method, its saying SQL dependacy classes not found. How can I publish my class file with those jar files. Everything I've done in cmd prompt.

Comment: If you want standalone executable jars, take a look at [onejar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) or adapt this guide to your needs: [fat-jars](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/getting-started/#building-fat-jars).

Comment: No, I have to publish that class file. I cant make it as executable jars.